# How do I get auto-generated SQL statements from NHibernate's operation?

Tags: nhibernate

I got a tricky problem. I have to record specified database operations into my database log table. It is a custom table, not relevant to any system database table. It takes the form of SQL statements, but I am using NHibernate as my data access methods.

So how do I make it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that all commands are logged would be to setup a SQL Trace and have it log all commands to a SQL Server table.

Comment: Not the only way, as other answers demonstrate, but this can often be the quickest way.

Answer (score 0):

While I would have to try it out myself to be sure, you should be able to use a custom interceptor to do this.  Check IInterceptor and inherit from EmptyInterceptor.  Something like this should work:

```
public class LogSqlInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor {     
  public SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql) {
    logger.Log(sql.ToString());
  }
}
```

logger is obviously whatever you are using to log the sql statements.  It could just be File.WriteLine().  I am fairly certain this will do what you want but I can't test it right now.